# What is wrong with this fake proof that any subset of a $T_1$ space is closed?

Tags: general-topology, fake-proofs

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space and let $A \subseteq X$ be any subset.

*Fake Proof:* Since $X$ is $T_1$ we know that any singleton in $X$ is closed. So choose $a \in A$, then $\{a\}$ is closed and $X \setminus \{a\}$ is open in $X$. Now choose another $a' \in A$ such that  $a' \neq a$. Then again $\{a'\}$ is closed and $(X \setminus \{a\}) \setminus \{a'\} = X \setminus \{a, a'\}$ is open since it is the set difference of an open and closed set.

Continue this process for all $a \in A$ and thus we've shown $X \setminus A$ is open and hence that $A$ is closed. $\square$

---

My guess is that when we say "continue this process" that's where some subtlety lies which would show that this proof is incorrect, but I can't say what that subtlety is. If $A$ was finite this proof would work fine I think.

So my question is, what exactly is wrong with this proof?

Comment: You have a perfectly fine proof that in a $T_1$ space, any *finite* subset is closed. But of course, that follows easily from the fact that a finite union of closed sets is closed, and singletons are closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right. The "continue this process" hides that we get $A$ is closed via $$X\backslash A=\bigcap_{a\in A}(X\backslash\{a\}).$$

If $A$ is infinite, this is an infinite intersection of open sets, which is not necessarily open.